# picker in settings bundle

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, ios

I'm trying to use the Settings Bundle to set preferences for my app.
 Am I able to use a picker in the settings bundle? The documentation doesn't seem to indicate that I am, but the Nike + iPod app seems to use a picker for Weight.
If yes can any one give some idea or any tutorial for that.

Thanks in advance

Comment: I don't have Nike+iPod app, can you post a screenshot of that picker?

Answer (score -1):

Your view controller should impliment the `<UIPickerViewDelegate>`protocol

Then impliment the picker view delegates `didSelectRow` method something like so:

```
- (void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component{
        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:[pickerData objectAtIndex:row] forKey:@"mySettingKey"];
        //my setting is the key for your setting in the bundle which you would set inside the .plist editor
    }
```

Comment: Sorry after reading your question again I realize you mean in the settings application on the iphone. This code example would be to change the setting with a picker from within the app itself. Sorry for the confusion.